# android LocationServices Api not getting location updates when in background

Tags: android

```
public class LocationService extends BaseService implements
    LocationListener, Orientation.Listener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {                    

    @Nullable        
    @Override        
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { 
        return null;
    }            

    @Override        
    public void onCreate() {            
        super.onCreate();                        
        createLocationRequest();                           
        //Location request
        builder mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)                   
            .build();            
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();                
    }            

    protected void createLocationRequest() {            
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }                    

    @Override        
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);        
    }                


    @Override        
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {            
        try {                
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);               
        }            
        catch (SecurityException e) { }
    }

    @Override        
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }         

    @Override        
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
        // if(location.isFromMockProvider()){
        // Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: From mock location");
        // } else {
        speed = location.getSpeed() * 18 / 5;                
        mCurrentLocation = location;                
        LatLng local = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.isRiding, false)) {
            locationArray.add(local);    
            //Log.d("location", "onLocationChanged: " + local);
        }                    

        if (lStart == null) {                    
            lStart = mCurrentLocation;                    
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;                
        } else {           
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;                
            updateUI();
        }           
    }            

    @Override        
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }                 

    private void updateUI() {
        // doing something here
    }                          

     public void connect() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
     }                

    public static Location returnLocation() {                
        return mCurrentLocation;        
    }
}
```

**I am using google api client along with locationservices api to get location in background, and its working fine when phone is unlocked but when phone is locked am not getting location updates what am i doing wrong?

It used to work before but i dunno why its not working now 
**

Comment: running on android 0 ? Do check back ground location limits https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html

Comment: no i tried it on lollipop,marshmallow and nougat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any one who faces the same issue in future

I had degraded my location api in application gradle from com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2 to
com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.2